# Unable to run query:You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause, sql-like

I am getting variables substituted by Ajax through selection, and then these variables are being used in php file. The variable values are displayed well,but when used in Sql Qyery it gives error like: Unable to run query:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-part WHERE BANK = 'State Bank of Mysore ' AND STATE = 'Maharashtra' AND ADDRESS' at line 1.

This is my code:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM bankifsc-part
 WHERE BANK = '$bank' 
AND STATE = '$state' AND ADDRESS LIKE '%$city%'";
```

Comment: Use ticks for your table name: \`bankifsc-part\` because it contains dash.

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the table name in ``:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `bankifsc-part`
 WHERE BANK = '$bank' 
AND STATE = '$state' AND ADDRESS LIKE '%$city%'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the table name in back ticks `` as the table name contain hyphen.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM `bankifsc-part`
 WHERE BANK = '$bank' 
AND STATE = '$state' AND ADDRESS LIKE '%$city%'";
```

In MySQL, use the back-ticks. In standard SQL, use double-quotes.